# Не отображается блок только на MacBook

Tags: javascript, html, css

В корзине у нас есть блок выбора оплат, 2й способ оплаты частями отображается на Windows , на MacBook почему то нет

Куда копать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть браузер (непонятно пока какой) один и тот-же, а результат разный? А где используемая разметка? Используется ли JavaScript для этого? P.S.: замените "частями" на рассрочку, т.к. непонятно относится ли это к отображению блока или к оплате.

Comment: Только в хроме однако почему то отображается

Comment: Дополняйте информацией вопрос, а не комментарии. Чудес на свете не бывает, а значит используется либо какая-то HTML/CSS/JS спецификация с ограниченной, либо экспериментальной поддержкой, либо... Тут гадать долго можно без кода стилей и т.д.

Comment: Решил вопрос
Проблема на бэке была в условиях ((